# How to add an image or a hyperlink to the TeamCity test fail report or/and to the build log?

Tags: c#, teamcity

Is it possible to add an image or a hyperlink to the TeamCity test fail report or/and to the build log? We would like to have this additional information when our UI tests fail. Ideally - it will be great to build the screenshot into the test error description, but another option is also fine (hyperlink to the screenshot). Tests are written in C# and MsTest is used to run them.

Thanks

Comment: When question starts with `Is it possible` I can always answer YES. It just depends on amount of time and effort invested. Have you tried anything to achieve your goal? Please share your research results, we don't want to duplicate work you already did.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish the results and any images as html file(s), see official documentation [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results). The image you want won't be available in the **Build Logs** tab, but will be on the html page in a new tab beside.

Alternatively, you can print a link to the build log and it will be picked up as a hyperlink, provided you use the [Teamcity output format](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity).